# When Merging Pandas DataFrames of Different Time Intervals, How to Fill NaNs with Constant Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm merging one Pandas DataFrame of LARGE time intervals into another DataFrame of SMALL time intervals and would like the merged column's values to remain constant instead of NaN.
As the date ascends I would like the population to stay the same until updated, not show NaN.

DataFrame A

```
DATE, Close, High, Low, Open
959731080000000 106.600 106.600 106.600 106.600     
959731380000000 106.650 106.650 106.650 106.650     
959732340000000 106.640 106.650 106.640 106.650     
959732880000000 106.660 106.660 106.660 106.660     
959733180000000 106.670 106.670 106.670 106.670  
959733240000000 106.660 106.660 106.660 106.660 
959734200000000 106.610 106.610 106.580 106.580 
959734320000000 106.600 106.600 106.600 106.600 
959735820000000 106.620 106.620 106.620 106.620 
959736240000000 106.630 106.640 106.630 106.630 
959736540000000 106.620 106.620 106.620 106.620 
959736780000000 106.640 106.670 106.640 106.670
959736960000000 106.690 106.690 106.690 106.690 
959743320000000 106.690 106.700 106.690 106.700 
959745660000000 106.700 106.750 106.250 106.260 
959745720000000 106.270 106.280 106.270 106.280
959745900000000 106.270 106.270 106.270 106.270
```

DataFrame B

```
DATE, Population
959731080000000 123.456     
959732880000000 124.834    
959736780000000 125.456
```

Merged B into A

```
A = A.merge(B, how='left')

DATE, Close, High, Low, Open, Population
959731080000000 106.600 106.600 106.600 106.600 123.456    
959731380000000 106.650 106.650 106.650 106.650 NaN    
959732340000000 106.640 106.650 106.640 106.650 NaN    
959732880000000 106.660 106.660 106.660 106.660 124.834    
959733180000000 106.670 106.670 106.670 106.670 NaN 
959733240000000 106.660 106.660 106.660 106.660 NaN
959734200000000 106.610 106.610 106.580 106.580 NaN
959734320000000 106.600 106.600 106.600 106.600 NaN
959735820000000 106.620 106.620 106.620 106.620 NaN
959736240000000 106.630 106.640 106.630 106.630 NaN
959736540000000 106.620 106.620 106.620 106.620 NaN
959736780000000 106.640 106.670 106.640 106.670 125.456
959736960000000 106.690 106.690 106.690 106.690 NaN
959743320000000 106.690 106.700 106.690 106.700 NaN
959745660000000 106.700 106.750 106.250 106.260 NaN
959745720000000 106.270 106.280 106.270 106.280 NaN
959745900000000 106.270 106.270 106.270 106.270 NaN
```

I would like the Population numbers to fill the NaN cells like this (as the Population numbers would be constant in reality)

```
DATE, Close, High, Low, Open, Population
959731080000000 106.600 106.600 106.600 106.600 123.456    
959731380000000 106.650 106.650 106.650 106.650 123.456
959732340000000 106.640 106.650 106.640 106.650 123.456
959732880000000 106.660 106.660 106.660 106.660 124.834    
959733180000000 106.670 106.670 106.670 106.670 124.834
959733240000000 106.660 106.660 106.660 106.660 124.834
959734200000000 106.610 106.610 106.580 106.580 124.834
959734320000000 106.600 106.600 106.600 106.600 124.834
959735820000000 106.620 106.620 106.620 106.620 124.834
959736240000000 106.630 106.640 106.630 106.630 124.834
959736540000000 106.620 106.620 106.620 106.620 124.834
959736780000000 106.640 106.670 106.640 106.670 125.456
959736960000000 106.690 106.690 106.690 106.690 125.456
959743320000000 106.690 106.700 106.690 106.700 125.456
959745660000000 106.700 106.750 106.250 106.260 125.456
959745720000000 106.270 106.280 106.270 106.280 125.456
959745900000000 106.270 106.270 106.270 106.270 125.456
```

===============================================================
I tried storing the B column population numbers as a list and looping through the A column's population column with an if statement. It does nothing.

```
series = [i for i in B['POPULATION']]
for i in A['POPULATION']:
    for k in series:
        if i == k:
            A['POPULATION'].fillna(k)
```

Comment: There is some problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
A = pd.merge_asof(A,B,on='DATE')
print (A)
               DATE   Close    High     Low    Open  Population
0   959731080000000  106.60  106.60  106.60  106.60     123.456
1   959731380000000  106.65  106.65  106.65  106.65     123.456
2   959732340000000  106.64  106.65  106.64  106.65     123.456
3   959732880000000  106.66  106.66  106.66  106.66     124.834
4   959733180000000  106.67  106.67  106.67  106.67     124.834
5   959733240000000  106.66  106.66  106.66  106.66     124.834
6   959734200000000  106.61  106.61  106.58  106.58     124.834
7   959734320000000  106.60  106.60  106.60  106.60     124.834
8   959735820000000  106.62  106.62  106.62  106.62     124.834
9   959736240000000  106.63  106.64  106.63  106.63     124.834
10  959736540000000  106.62  106.62  106.62  106.62     124.834
11  959736780000000  106.64  106.67  106.64  106.67     125.456
12  959736960000000  106.69  106.69  106.69  106.69     125.456
13  959743320000000  106.69  106.70  106.69  106.70     125.456
14  959745660000000  106.70  106.75  106.25  106.26     125.456
15  959745720000000  106.27  106.28  106.27  106.28     125.456
16  959745900000000  106.27  106.27  106.27  106.27     125.456
```

Comment: On my end this seems to be just making the entire column the first population number. 123.456 every number all the way down.

Comment: @Renoldus - Can you check now?

Comment: Then use `B = B.sort_values('DATE')` before `merge_asof`

Comment: I see. My dates are not what I thought they were.

Comment: I've deleted the question because of my mistakes in the 'DATE' columns. I don't want to get downvotes for a bad question. Maybe you'll still get points for best answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this-

```
for i in A['Population']:
   if i != NaN:
      prev = i
   else:
      i = prev
```